# How to execute a file without execute permissions

Tags: permissions

Let's say `user` wants to execute a script `test.sh` but `ls -l test.sh` gives

```
 -rwxrwxr-- 1 root root 96 Feb 25 21:44 test.sh
```

Now if `user` doesn't want to make a copy of `test.sh` (on which he does `chmod +x`), he can simply do

```
sh test.sh
```

to execute `test.sh`.

Is there an analogue way to execute binary programs which one doesn't have execute permissions?

Comment: `sudo <program>` - see [`man sudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo)

Comment: @garethTheRed Doesn't work here for a script file; command not found.

Comment: @Murphy - the OP asked for a way to do this with binary programs.

Comment: @garethTheRed Tried it with a local copy of `chmod`, same result when the exec bits are unset. Perhaps this behaviour is controlled by a `sudo` setting?

Comment: @Murphy - assume `-rwxrwxr-- root root 86 Feb 25 21:44 test` in `/usr/bin`.  User `doe` doesn't have execute permission for this, but can run it with `sudo test`.  Or have I misread the question?

Comment: @garethTheRed No, you didn't, and the fault is entirely on my side. I assumed the file is completely missing the exec flags for all access groups, and some others (@MelBurslan) too, it seems. Of course `sudo` should be absolutely valid for the OPs case. Shouldn't your contribution be an answer, then?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Basically this is the same thing as one of the very famous UNIX technical interview questions, known for ages:

*Assume someone with root access ran a command `chmod -R 444 /` and made the `chmod` binary non-executable. How do you recover from it ?*

There is a perl answer and there is this one, which basically is running a non-executable program, `chmod` in this case:

```
/lib/ld-linux.so /bin/chmod +x /bin/chmod
```

I think you can apply it to any other program that you know is executable. Otherwise be ready to embrace the disaster, which may ensue

PS> `/lib/ld-linux.so` might differ in name. So if the direct match is not available, look around for similarly named `so`'s. For instance on my CentOS 6 server, it is `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` which is a symlink pointing to `/lib/ld-2.12.so`. So, your mileage may vary.

Comment: Well, if you did a `chmod -R 444 /`, then `/lib/ld-linux.so` won't be executable either. If your (still running) shell is zsh, you can do `zmodload zsh/files` which gives you a builtin chmod. If it's `ksh93`, you can do `command /opt/ast/bin/chmod` to get a  builtin chmod as well.

Comment: Note that the ld-linux.so trick only works for dynamically linked programs.

Comment: /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /bin/ls
/bin/ls: error while loading shared libraries: /bin/ls: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64

Comment: @viuser The command worked for me, and `file` returns the same ELF format on both files.

Comment: @viuser try `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so /bin/ls` instead. The version in /lib is for 32-bit executables.

Comment: I got error `Standalone execution is not enabled`

Answer (score -1):

If the user doesn't have execute permission and cannot or is not willing to have it changed, then they must execute it as a group or user who does have execute permission.

If they know the root password then:

```
su -c <executable>
```

If they don't know the root password, but are trusted with `sudo` then:

```
sudo <executable>
```

If they don't know the root password and are not trusted with `sudo` privileges, then there is a reason why they should run the executable.